# How to design a database where multiple users can own the same object ( a Refrigerator )?

Tags: database

Currently I have 2 tables. A User table and a Refrigerator table.

Now multiple users can add a refrigerator and have access to its data.
Also multiple users can own multiple refrigerators.

I was thinking of making another table which will hold foreignkey to both User and Refrigerator table like so

- user -> name, email
- refrigirator -> model, other fields
- user_refrigerator -> user_id,
  refrigerator_id

Is there a better design option to accomplish this task?

Comment: This is the right approach. When dealing with n:m relationships a separate table that holds the relations (user_refrigerator in your example) is the way to go.

Comment: @Stefan cool, thanks